# Generate Class Instance In Python

Tags: python, iteration, instance

I have been having trouble getting python to generate a (non-predetermined) number of class instances. Basically have classes be able to reproduce themselves.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

while True:
    newinstance(foo) #what would the code be for this?
                     #or maybe
    foo.newinstance  #just something that could update itself
```

Basically generate a new instance any number of times. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: I know how to make a new instance, I meant generate an unspecified amount of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you're asking for, but you'll want to hold onto the values somehow:

```
while True:
    foo(some_name)
```

This will loop forever, so a more realistic option might be:

```
names = ["Ned", "Felix", "Guy"]
fooses = [foo(name) for name in names]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
instances_of_foo = [foo("bar") for i in range(number_of_instances)]
```

Also, if you would like to pass different arguments to each instance, you can create of list of args instead of using `range()`.

```
list_of_args = [args_for_instance_one, args_for_instance_two,...]

instances_of_foo = [foo(arg) for arg in list_of_args]
```

Comment: No list was mentioned in the question. It's reasonable to presume that the asker wanted a list, but `name_list` needs to be explained to the asker (given the mention of 'a number of times', `range()` might make more sense).

Comment: @Lattyware yes, but he would like to be able to generate a certain amount at run time so he will need a collection to hold them. This is definitely the best answer.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Yes, a list will be needed to store the instances - I was referring to the other list.

Comment: @Lattyware: You are right, but this provides an easy way to both instantiate and hold on to the references in one line. Plus, it's easy to understand.

Comment: @Lattyware: Just read your edited comment. Editing my question.

Comment: I was just saying if the poster goes and does instance = foo(new instance) he's going to end up with no references to his objects and no idea what's going wrong. The necessity for a list is implicit.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Yes, I completely agree - the original answer had the list of arguments with no explanation, I was saying that it needed some. The list to store the instances is completely needed and I have no issue with that.

Comment: @Lattyware That was a good call. He certainly needs to understand the collection aspect of it if he intends to create instance at run time. If he doesn't understand that, he still won't know how to reference the objects later on.